# Can i use others YouTube video for my youtube channel for non commercial purpose

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-basis

Can I upload other's YouTube videos on my YouTube channel after doing a little editing....I am not using these videos for commercial purposes....is it legal for me...if I can upload the video on my channel without permission or without adding my name by doing some editing or changing the voice or just using the voice and without attribution. My aim is not to earn money from this, I will delete these videos later and will upload my own made videos….is this acceptable for me in islam….